# How can I write the Gompertz SDE in matlab?

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

I have the sde as SDE=(a*x(t)-c*x(t)*log(x(t)))*dt+b*x(t)*dW(t);
with a=0.1; b=0.2;c=0.3. I was wondering how to implement that into matlab and get a graph as  I have been unable to get anywhere so far?

Comment: how do you use mathjax in matlab?

Comment: not familiar with matlab, but this link might help: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/differential-equations.html